# proper regex to tokenize sentence with leading dash

Tags: regex

Here is the regex i'm using for tokenizer: `[^a-zA-Z\'-]+`

However, if I want to apply it to sentence like this:
`-This is a test. -yes, it's a test for self-consciousness`
The result would be `['-This', 'is', 'a', 'test', '-yes', "it's", 'a', 'test', 'for', 'self-consciousness']` where there is leading `-` ahead of `This` and `yes`. Is there gonna be a way to eliminate the leading `-`? Maybe some modification on the regex i'm using?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Ql7lWq/1

Answer (score 1):

You'd need something to qualify the dash in the middle.

Since you are using the negatives to split it up, you have to allow
the wrong dashes to be matched.

`(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]|(?<![a-zA-Z'])-|-(?![a-zA-Z']))+`

https://regex101.com/r/Ql7lWq/1

```
 (?:
      [^a-zA-Z'-]         # not any of these
   |                    # or,
      (?<!                # allow a dash if not preceded by one of the others
           [a-zA-Z'] 
      )
      -
   |                    # or,
      -                   # allow a dash if not followed by one of the others
      (?! [a-zA-Z'] )
 )+
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
[^a-zA-Z']+
```

I recommend using this website below. It helps to debug something like this.

> https://regexr.com/

Comment: Not this one, it will split self-consciousness to `self` and `consciousness`

Answer (score 0):

```
-?[^a-zA-Z-']+-?|^-|-$
```

This `-?` optional dash is what we are looking for.

Comment: You would think this might work, but it's not granular enough. Try `(?:-?[^a-zA-Z-']-?)+|^-+|-+$` Also, it won't match abc`---`efg which may  or may not be a part of a hyphenated word, because it's not qualified with a .`[^a-zA-Z-']`